# status message of the buddy through xmpp in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, xmpp

I am getting the buddy list correctly. Also the online, busy, offline also getting.
But I also want to show the status message of the buddy.
For this I am using  `XMPPResourceCoreDataStorage` class object. I am using this method `resourceForJID`:  of class `XMPPUserCoreDataStorage` to get the resource to show the status.

But I am getting `XMPPResourceCoreDataStorage` as a nil.

Comment: XMPPResourceCoreDataStorageObject*  userResource = (XMPPResourceCoreDataStorageObject*)[user resourceForJID:[user.jid bareJID]]; and in the XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject comment some line of code. then it will work. But when buddy went offline, offline presence is not updating. May be I am doing some wrong. If you find please let me know.  //                     NSString *jidStr = [jid full];for (XMPPResourceCoreDataStorageObject *resource in [self resources])
 {
//  if ([jidStr isEqualToString:[resource jidStr]])
//  {
   return resource;
//  }
 }
 
 return nil;

Comment: To show the presence status of the buddy subscription should be 'both'

Comment: Hello, I am trying to integrate XMPP Server in my iPhone application, but not able to get online users, in presence delegate method, it returns 0 users however in Jabber server there 3 or 4 users are online, so what is the problem behind that ? please help, stuck from last 3 days

Comment: To get the proper presence status "Subscribtion type should be both". Check in server side what subscribtion you have with your's buddy.

Comment: U know how to get acknowldgement from xmpp when message has sent or received ? And Is their generate any id when user has sent or received message from XMPP ?